# Number of threads in threadpool using GUI elements

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about performance,
I have a program that has 10 GUI elements, and I run them simultaneously with threadpools, for that I use 10 threads , but I wanted to optimize the program, and I've read that you can use the number of cores your PC has and it will have the same effect, so I used this:

```
if(competition.getActiveCompetitors().size()>Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
                 numberOfThreads=Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
            else
                numberOfThreads=competition.getActiveCompetitors().size();
            es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
```

competition.getActiveCompetitors.size()  is the number 10 gui elements ( may vary based on the user input), and I used Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() to determine the number of threadpools, for example I had 4, so when I runned 10 elements, only 4 ran, and after they finished the other 4 ran aswell, is there a way I can make the entire 10 elements run with 4 threads? or i'm thinking about it all wrong

Comment: Why not just use a thread pool? Or I am missing something?

Comment: The number of cores will determine the number threads that can run be executing at the same time (one in each core). You can have more Threads  "running" at the same time by sharing each core. For the end user this shareing is precived as "executing at the same time". You should see this happening if the processes you are running are not cpu intensive (have i/o calls like reading or writting to a device)